# Change windows user password with python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, python-2.6, change-password

I am looking for a way to change the windows password throgh a python script.
  somthing like a win32api that can help me?
  Thanks!

Comment: You first need to fiquere out where the password is stored. Then modify that file, if that is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "the windows password"? Are you referring to a password on a user account?

Comment: @Tenzin No, that's not how to do this. The correct way would be with an API function if it existed.

Comment: @MrEricSir - I'm talking about windows user password.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Do you know such a function?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Win32 function [`NetUserChangePassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370650.aspx). From Python you can access that with [`win32net.NetUserChangePassword`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32net__NetUserChangePassword_meth.html).

Although as the documentation points out this won't work if you are using active directory. But in that case you are surely not in a position to change user passwords programmatically.

Comment: You could also execute `subprocess.call("net user username newpassword")`. See [net user](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771865).